# Importing CSV with jsonb and array with PGAdmin4

Tags: database, postgresql, import, pgadmin

I am trying PGAdmin4 to import. Whenever I run the import it throws this error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "size" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: {size...
COPY media, line 1, column details: "{size: 1097267, width: 2950, height: 2094, dateTime: null, latitude: null, longitude: null, cameraMo..."
```

**Table Structure:**

```
ID (int) name(text) details(jsonb) tags(text[])
```

**Data:**

```
   27   Beautiful beach {"size": 1097267, "width": 2950}    {amazing,asia,attraction}
```

PG Admin Import Settings:
[image]

Comment: Per here [JSON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) `jsonb` input needs to be `'{"size": 1097267, "width": 2950, ...}'` whereas the error is showing that is formatted as `"{size: 1097267, width: 2950, ...}`. You need to figure out why that is happening.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I tried with `'{"size": 1097267, "width": 2950, ...}'` the error remains the same

Comment: Tried what? Also are you using `text` or `csv` format? **Add answers as update to question**.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a database archive (.tar) and restored it via PGAdmin database restore option.
It Worked.